# how to get my app to recognize images from the cloud?

Tags: unity-game-engine, metaio, junaio

I can't figure out how to get my Unity app to recognize images from the cloud using the Metaio SDK. Could anyone point me to the method, API or tutorial to allow this on Unity/Metaio?

For example, I've got my Unity app working with Metaio to recognize a local image, that is, an image that I've placed in the Resources folder. I would like to build an app that can recognize images in the cloud (metaio servers) such that no image file would need to be bundled into the application itself.

Some details: I'm using Unity Pro 4.5.5 with Metaio SDK 6.0, trying to build an app for Android

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. The answer to your first question is yes, although I don't know how, I understand the technology stack enough to answer that.

You seem to have a specific question in here as well as the generic one though, this channel ID thing - maybe be more specific about what you want there...

Comment: Thanks, I will edit for clarity.. ultimately, I can only figure out how to build a Metaio app in Unity that recognizes local images. I can't figure out how to build/configure the app to recognize an image I uploaded to the cloud (metaio servers)

Comment: You can do that with Vuforia and it's plugin for Unity3d. It stores images in the cloud and, by implementing an interface, you can detect recognition events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Metaio SDK installer includes example of Cloud based image recognition a.k.a. Visual Search. Please refer to the Visual Search scene in the Unity example. More information can be found here: https://dev.metaio.com/visual-search/general-information/

Comment: Thank you! I was confusing their 'Cloud' plugin with their CVS functionality.